# Confused with (trivial?) geometric probability problem.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am preparing the the probability test. I faced the problem that is expected to be trivial, but I fear I do not get the most essential part of it.

Ok, let point $M$ is located on the ray $R = \{y=0, x \geq 1\}$ in the $(x,y)$ plane. M has Pareto distribution with probability density function $p(x) = 1/x^2,\, x \ge 1$. Let $d(x)$ is distance from $M$ to $(0, 1)$. **NOTE: not to (1,0)!** I have to find

1. Cumulative distribution function of $d$.
2. Probability density function of $d$.
3. Expected value of $d$.

If I would know how to do $1$ or $2$ I have no doubts that I should be able to handle two other parts of the problem, but I simply do not understand how and why $p(x)$ and $d(x)$ are related.

I feel there should be some use of Pythagorean theorem and integration/differentiation, but I I do not understand the most essential step (and more importantly intuition and explanation behind it) - how to move from $p(x)$ to $d(x)$. What is going on here? How can probability density function be related with position? What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some notational sloppiness in the statement of the problem. The point $M$ is not a random variable, but its $x$-coordinate is. And the quantity $d(x)$ is a random variable but it's not explained what $x$ is.

It would make more sense if the problem were:

> Point $M$ is located on the ray $R=\{ y=0,x\ge1\}$ in the $(x,y)$ plane. $\color{red}{\text{The $x$-coordinate of}}$ $M$ has Pareto distribution with probability density function $p(x)=\frac1{x^2}, x\ge1$. Let $\color{red}D$ be the distance from $M$ to $(0,1)$.

With this formulation you can observe (using Pythagoras) that $D=\sqrt{X^2+1}$ where $X$ stands for the (random) $x$-coordinate of $M$. You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.. I expected answer similar to this one and I am happy with it, because I thought something very similar but was completely unsure if I understand that.